# Avoid references in PyYAML

Tags: python, yaml

I use YAML with PyYAML. Is there a way to avoid the *id002 references after dumping a nested structure? For readability I'd like to see the actual (tuple) values there.

While trying to produce a mini example I noticed that it only happens when I use the same id object:

```
import yaml

t = ("b", "c")
x = {(1, t):1, (2, t):2, }
print(yaml.dump(x))
```

So I thought `copy.copy()` would solve the problem, however for tuples it doesn't seem to work :( Can I create a new tuple with a different id?

Comment: Perhaps you could show code so we can repro

Comment: Does it work with `x = {(1, t):1, (2, tuple(t)):2}`?

Comment: No :( Somehow `a=(1,); a is tuple(a)` also predicts that there is no new tuple.

Comment: Ah, but `tuple(list(t))` works :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The PyYAML dumper uses an `ignore_aliases` method to prevent primitive types from being "anchored" and "referenced" in this way. You can override that method to always ignore_aliases independent of any object passed in. And by default the `yaml.Loader` class is used in `yaml.load`¹:

```
t = ("b", "c")
x = {(1, t):1, (2, t):2, }

yaml.Dumper.ignore_aliases = lambda *args : True

yaml.dump(x, sys.stdout)
```

will get you:

```
? !!python/tuple
- 1
- !!python/tuple [b, c]
: 1
? !!python/tuple
- 2
- !!python/tuple [b, c]
: 2
```

That way you don't have to try your best and get tuples with the same hash to look different. You might want to provide the `default_flow_style` parameter on `yaml.load` to `False` or `True` to get different layouts of the output.

The reason you could not get this to work is that the representer matches the result of `id()` and that is the same for two tuples generated separately as long as the elements are the same.

---

¹ <sub>In [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml), of which I am the author, which is an enhanced version of PyYAML, capable of handling YAML 1.2, you can do:</sub>

```
    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
    yaml.representer.ignore_aliases = lambda *args: True
```

Comment: Also, if you are using the `yaml.safe_dump()` to remove the `? !!python/tuple` from the yaml. You will need to overwrite the `yaml.SafeDumper.ignore_aliases`. The example then becomes: 

`yaml.SafeDumper.ignore_aliases = lambda *args : True`
 and 
`yaml.safe_dump(x, sys.stdout)`

Comment: FWIW this is now working (PyYAML 5.3.1).  On some of less recent versions of PyYAML setting this caused an exception, at least in my code.

Comment: Thanks! It's annoying that it's 2021 and the latest PyYAML version still requires this trick to work properly.

Comment: @RafaelAlves, your answer doesn't work with a yaml.safe_dump() call on my host.  Does PyYAML have to be a certain version to make your code work?

Answer (score 9):

[This method](https://ttl255.com/yaml-anchors-and-aliases-and-how-to-disable-them/) works for me on Python 2 and Python 3, and does not require monkeypatching:

```py
import yaml

class NoAliasDumper(yaml.SafeDumper):
    def ignore_aliases(self, data):
        return True

t = ("b", "c")
x = {(1, t):1, (2, t):2, }
print(yaml.dump(x, Dumper=NoAliasDumper))
```

which yields

```
? - 1
  - [b, c]
: 1
? - 2
  - [b, c]
: 2
```

Comment: the answer in the link you provide (https://ttl255.com/yaml-anchors-and-aliases-and-how-to-disable-them/) works for me.

To others, when you override the yaml.SafeDumper() class, you *have* to use yaml.dump() not yaml.safe_dump() to get rid of the YAML references.  Using yaml.safe_dump() will result in this error: "TypeError: dump_all() got multiple values for keyword argument 'Dumper'