# Python YAML dumping pointer references

Tags: python, string, pointers, yaml

I'm trying to build a YAML doc using a couple of component templates.  I'm loading them, building a Python object, then trying to dump them (ultimately to a file, but this example just prints).  As you can see below, it's printing references and pointers instead of the string data I'm expecting.  What am I doing wrong (or not doing)?

This is an example I made to demonstrate my problem:

```
import yaml

main_template = yaml.load('organization: main')

sub_template = yaml.load('''
division: development
other:
  data:
  - for: users
''')

users = [ 'alice', 'bob', 'kim' ]

all_user_data = dict(main_template)

user_list = []

for user in users:
    tmp = dict(sub_template)
    tmp['name'] = user
    user_list.append(tmp)

all_user_data['users'] = user_list
print(yaml.dump(all_user_data, default_flow_style=False))
```

This produces:

```
organization: main
users:
- division: development
  name: alice
  other: &id001
    data:
    - for: users
- division: development
  name: bob
  other: *id001
- division: development
  name: kim
  other: *id001
```

I'm expecting output like this:

```
organization: main
users:
- division: development
  name: alice
  other:
    data:
    - for: users
- division: development
  name: bob
  other:
    data:
    - for: users
- division: development
  name: kim
  other:
    data:
    - for: users
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Anthon suggests in [Avoid references in PyYAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518819/avoid-references-in-pyyaml), you can do

```
yaml.Dumper.ignore_aliases = lambda *args : True
```

Then,

```
print(yaml.dump(all_user_data, default_flow_style=False))
```

yields

```
organization: main
users:
- division: development
  name: alice
  other:
    data:
    - for: users
- division: development
  name: bob
  other:
    data:
    - for: users
- division: development
  name: kim
  other:
    data:
    - for: users
```

I have no idea why this works. Kudos to Anthon.

Oliver

Comment: It works by replacing the method that checks if aliases do not need to be found by always returning True. So aliases are not searched for and each object is dumped as is. That is of course dangerous: if there is a loop in your data-structures your YAML file will become infinitely large. The preferred way to indicate that a question already has been answered on [so] is to close it as duplicate (or with  your reputation level, propose to close it)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and advice Anthon!