# List of same value, not same reference

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
>>> x = [(None, None), (None, None), (None, None)]
>>> y = [(None, None) for _ in range(3)]
>>> x[0] is x[1]
False
>>> y[0] is y[1]
True
```

I need a list of `n` values `(None, None)` that are not references to same value.

How do I make `y` behave like `x`, i.e., to not reference same value?

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459098/create-list-of-single-item-repeated-n-times) I expected `y` to behave like `x`...

This is using Python 3.6

Comment: >>> x[0] is x[1]
True
>>> y[0] is y[1]
True
>>> ................ I cannot replicate your result, what python version are you using? maybe that would work

Comment: Tuples are immutable, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: "I need a list of n values `(None, None)` that are not references to same value." - why? It is very rare for that to actually matter. This is a warning sign that you may be misunderstanding something and/or picking a bad design.

Comment: @Knl_Kolhe `Python 3.6.3 :: Intel Corporation` on Linux

Comment: @user2052436 Okay I ran it on Windows. Good to know.

Comment: I'm also wondering why you need this...

Comment: @HeapOverflow We later yaml-dump objects that contain such lists. And in case of `y`, dump contains stuff like `- &id001 !!python/tuple [null, null]` and later `- *id001`. The client, who reads yaml, doesn't want it.

Comment: So that's an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) then? And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13518819/12671057) is your real problem and its answer applies to your case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit strange to need two different-by-identity but equal-by-value tuples, but I've had legitimate reasons to do similarly strange things on occasion, so I think the question deserves an answer at face value.

The reason that `y` gives a list of three references to the same tuple is that the tuple `(None, None)` is a compile-time constant, so the bytecode for it is a simple `LOAD_CONST` which is done inside the list comprehension, and of course loading the same constant three times just creates three references to it, not three copies.

To get around this, we need an expression whose value is `(None, None)` but for which the expression is not a compile-time constant. A function call to `tuple` does it, at least in the versions of Python I tested (3.5.2 and 3.8.1):

```py
[tuple([None, None]) for _ in range(3)]
```

Frankly I'm a little surprised that `x` does have three different copies, and that is almost certainly an implementation-specific detail that you shouldn't rely on. But likewise, `tuple.__new__` does not always create a new tuple; for example `tuple( (None, None) )` returns a reference to the actual argument, not a copy of it. So it is not guaranteed that `tuple([None, None])` will continue to produce non-equal-by-reference tuples in other versions of Python.

Comment: I'd say it's highly unlikely that `tuple(no_tuple)` will deduplicate. For `tuple(a_tuple)` it's clear how and why it doesn't create a new tuple, and [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-tuple) also explicitly mention this case: *"If iterable is already a tuple, it is returned unchanged"*. Btw, this is apparently an XY problem after all, see the latest comments under the question.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the tuple function on a temporary list:

```
>>> x = [(None, None), (None, None), (None, None)]
>>> y = [tuple([None, None]) for _ in range(3)]
>>> x[0] is x[1]
False
>>> y[0] is y[1]
False
```

Answer (score 0):

`y = [tuple([None, None]) for _ in range(3)]` should work.