# create yaml with AWS CloudFormation references

Tags: python, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I need a python code that would create the yaml code below.

```
    Tags:
    - Key: key1
      Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
    - Key: Key2
      Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackId'
```

Here is what I have that doesn't do the trick.

```
def generate_resource(ami, source_data):
    resource = {
         "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
         "Properties": {
             "ImageId": ami["ImageId"],
             "InstanceType": ami["InstanceType"],
             "PrivateIpAddress": ami["PrivateIpAddress"],
             "KeyName": ami["KeyName"]
             "SubnetId": { "Ref": "SubnetId" },
             "SecurityGroupIds": { "Ref":  "SecurityGroupId" }, 
             "Tags": [
                 { "Key": "key1", "Value": "{!Ref 'AWS::StackName'}"},
                 { "Key": "key2", "Value": "{!Ref 'AWS::StackId'}"}
             ]
         }
     }
```

The `yaml` output from this code is not properly formatted so it simply copies `{!Ref 'AWS::StackName'}`, as the value.

```
import os, sys
import lib.aws as aws, lib.cft as cft, lib.inventory as inventory 

BUCKET_NAME = 'testbucket'


def generate_cft(commit_hash, file_dict, dry_run):
    return (
        "# Autogenerated CFT for commit hash " + commit_hash + "\n" + 
        cft.generate(inventory.read(file_dict["path"]))
    )


def upload_cft(commit_hash, file_dict, cft_text):
    target_key = commit_hash + "/" + file_dict["name"].split("_")[0] +    ".yaml"

    aws.upload(BUCKET_NAME, target_key, cft_text)


def show_cft(file_dict, cft_text):
    print(file_dict["path"] + " generates the following cft:")
    print("")
    print(cft_text)
    print("")


def generate_and_upload(commit_hash, file_dict, dry_run):
    cft_text = generate_cft(commit_hash, file_dict, dry_run)

    aws.validate_cft(cft_text)

    if dry_run: 
        show_cft(file_dict, cft_text)
    else:
        upload_cft(commit_hash, file_dict, cft_text)


def generate_and_upload_all(commit_hash, dry_run):
    for file_dict in inventory.list():
        print("generating cft for " + file_dict["path"])
        generate_and_upload(commit_hash, file_dict, dry_run)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not os.getcwd().endswith("ci"):
        print("Please run this script from the ci directory")
        exit()

    commit_hash = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) >= 2 else "test"
    generate_and_upload_all(commit_hash, False)
```

Comment: I would certainly _hope_ that a special value couldn't make the parser magically change something from being a string to being a reference -- think of all the damage folks looking for security issues could do by deliberately putting data in that form into software as inputs!

Comment: That said, _in general_: Serializers exist to accurately describe an in-memory structure in a manner compliant with a format specification. It's not generally the job of a serializer to make that data be represented in the specific way a user wants. If you review related questions such as [avoid references in pyyaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518819/avoid-references-in-pyyaml), you'll see that pyyaml _does_ use references when a structure contains multiple references to the same Python object, but that doesn't mean the user gets to configure those references' names.

Comment: You didn't include any code so it's going to be hard to help you. BTW these are AWS-specific features of CloudFormation templates, and you will likely have to pre/post-process them explicitly outside of your generic JSON to YAML conversion, perhaps using custom serialization.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ok thanks, excuse me.

Comment: @jarmod  I have updated the post and added the code for the resource. The yaml code above is what I need the python code to produce. Thanks

Comment: Where is the source code that attempts to emit the resource dict as YAML?

Comment: @jarmod  added the source code that generates the yaml. Thanks

Comment: You've included code that *calls* the code that generates the YAML, rather than the code that generates the YAML. What is `lib.cft`? Where is the code for the `cft.generate()` method?

Comment: @jarmod  this code is from the file generate_cft.py. after the cft is generated, it uploads it to testbucket in s3

Answer (score 0):

YES!!!! I played around with the code and figured it out. It was a syntax error during the CFT creation. now when I create a stack with the CFT generated, the tag value is replaced by the actual 'StackId'.. Thanks everyone for your help and guidance.

```
def generate_resource(ami, source_data):
resource = {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
    "Properties": {
        "ImageId": ami["ImageId"],
        "InstanceType": ami["InstanceType"],
        "PrivateIpAddress": ami["PrivateIpAddress"],
        "KeyName": ami["KeyName"],
        "SubnetId": { "Ref": "SubnetId" },
        "SecurityGroupIds": { "Ref":  "SecurityGroupId" }, 
        "Tags": [
            { "Key": "Name", "Value": ami["Name"] },
            { "Key": "BootUpDependsOn", "Value": ami["BootUpDependsOn"]},
            { "Key": "WaitTimeAfterBootUp", "Value": ami["WaitTimeAfterBootUp"]},
            { "Key": "Key1", "Value": { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" }},
            { "Key": "Key2", "Value": { "Ref": "AWS::StackId" }}
        ]
    }
}
```